# Testing whether a point overlaps a character on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas in which I need to draw text on in javascript, and then test whether given points overlap the text.

I am wondering if this is possible using the canvas (context.fillText(...)) and then some kind of test (if (overlap(textobject, {x:12, y:10{}) ) or whether I will need to draw the characters in SVG so I have the co-ordinates and can sort it from there?

I'm sure there are libraries out there that have started to pop up for this kind of thing but am having trouble with my google skills today.

Comment: If you must use canvas only, I would suggest filling your text to an otherwise-blank canvas (does not have to be on the page) and then using `getImageData()` to determine if the given pixel(s) are non-transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Being an open web fan and OOMG HTML5, I had completely ignored Flash. Turns out that it is the best medium for what i'm trying to do. And as actionscript and JS are so similar, the logic was a copy paste job.

---

Thanks heaps for the answers, it ended up being a huge ask, so I drew my characters in Illustrator, turned on the grid, created an array of where the grid crossed the character and where it didn't - and then turned that into a JS array. I'll publish a link once it's finished.

Answer (score 1):

I could think of a couple ways around this unless you are needing the text to be drawn to canvas for some type of pixel manipulation...

One way is float the text over the canvas element (position: absolute;) then test a hover event with jQuery. Another way is to create a box around the text in your canvas element, then detect when the mouse is within those bounds.

If you are looking for the most accurate test, svg would be the way to go.

You might also try out a library and see if they have already created this functionality. [easel js](http://easeljs.com/)